# Non-exhaustive pattern in function error despite the data handling being handled elsewhere

Tags: parsing, haskell, evaluation

I'm trying to write a simple language and at the moment I'm trying to implement a loop but every time I run the program, I get an error that there's a non-exhaustive pattern in the `evalStatement_` function.

```
----- Main -----
readStatement :: String -> IO [HStatement]
readStatement input = do
        program <- readFile input
        case parse parseProgram "Olivia" program of
          Left err -> fail $ show err
          Right parsed -> return $ parsed


evalString :: Env -> String -> IO String
evalString env expr = do
        x <- readStatement expr
        concat <$> mapM (runIOThrows . liftM show . evalStatement_ env) x
        --mapM (runIOThrows . liftM show . evalStatement env) x

        -- evalStatement env x
        --map (\exprs -> runIOThrows $ liftM show $ evalStatement env exprs) x
        --map (runIOThrows $ liftM show $ evalStatement env) x
        --runIOThrows $ liftM show $ (evalStatement env x)   -- >>= runIOThrows $ liftM show $ evalStatement env

evalAndPrint :: Env -> String -> IO ()
evalAndPrint env expr = do
        evalString env expr
        return ()

run :: String -> IO ()
run expr = nullEnv >>= flip evalAndPrint expr

main :: IO ()
main = do
        args   <- getArgs
        run $ args !! 0

----- Error -----
Main: Expr.hs:(82,1)-(85,34): Non-exhaustive patterns in function evalStatement_
-----------------

evalStatement_ :: Env -> HStatement -> IOThrowsError ()
evalStatement_ env (Do cond expr) = evalDo env (Do cond expr)
evalStatement_ env (Print val) = do
         x <- evalVal env val
         liftIO $ putStrLn $ show x 

evalDo :: Env -> HStatement -> IOThrowsError ()
evalDo env (Do cond expr) = evalVal env cond >>= \x -> case x of
                                                           HBool False -> return ()
                                                           HBool True  -> do
                                                                   traverse_ (evalVal env) expr
                                                                   evalStatement_ env $ Do cond expr

evalVal :: Env -> HVal -> IOThrowsError HVal
evalVal env val @(HInteger _) = return $ val
evalVal env val @(HBool    _) = return $ val
evalVal env val @(HString  _) = return $ val
evalVal env val @(HList    _) = return $ val
evalVal env (Arith x op y)    = evalArithmetic env x op y
evalVal env (Assign var val)  = evalVal env val >>= defineVar env var
```

I isolated the error down to these functions. I use `evalStatement_` to evaluate the `Do` and `Print` functions. I have tested `print` and it does work but I don't understand why `evalDo` doesn't. `evalVal` works as intended so I'm at a loss as to where the non-exhaustive problem resides. I ran the compile command with `-Wall -Wextra` and it gave me the following based on the Statement data type.

```
Expr.hs:82:1: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘evalStatement_’:
        Patterns not matched:
            _ (Eval _)
            _ (Program _)
   |
82 | evalStatement_ env (Do cond expr) = evalDo env (Do cond expr)
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...

 data HStatement
   =  Eval   HVal
   |  Print  HVal
   |  Do     HVal [HVal]
   |  Program [HVal]
    deriving (Eq, Read)
```

I'm not sure why `Eval` and `Program` would have bearing on something which doesn't actually used them or am I missing something completely?

Comment: If `Eval` and `Program` are `HStatement`s, then you need to make sure those are covered too. Otherwise, you should make functions for only `Print` and `Do`.

Comment: What happens if you pass `Eval x` to `evalStatement_`?

Comment: Passing `Eval x` to `evalStatement_` causes an expectation of `IOThrowsError`. It's function was to evaluated `HVal` data such that I could evaluate them but with regard to `IOThrowsError ()` rather than `IOThrowsError HVal`

Comment: Why would `Eval` and `Program` need to be included since they're not used with regards to evaluating the loop

Comment: The problem is exactly as the error message says. What is supposed to happen if your function `evalDo` receives as its second argument an HStatement object like `Program someList` ? As far as the compiler is able to tell, it can happen; the type system does not protect against this. In fact, you need a single evalHStatement function with 4 clauses, one per HStatement constructor, rather than 4 separate (partial) functions, about which the compiler is bound to complain.

Comment: @jpmarinier See I was going on the assumption that the argument given would always be in the form of `Do cond expr` but I see the error in that now! What you said makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @jpmarinier, this doesn't explain the **RUNTIME** error at the top of the question.  I believe the poster is asking why this runtime error is occurring if `evalStatement_` is never called with anything other than `Do` and `Print`, not asking why the compiler warning with `-Wall` has identified unmatched patterns.

Comment: The answer might be that `evalStatement_` is actually being called elsewhere in the code with something other than `Do` or `Print`.  Or, it might be that there's something fishy going on, since the end of the run-time error span `(85,34)` points to the space between `show` and `x`, instead of the `x` -- either a cut and paste error in the question, or maybe the poster is testing a program that's actually different than the source.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr I've added the section in `Main.hs` where `evalStatement_` is called but that's honestly the only other place where its called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `main` program appears to run `evalStatement_` sequentially on the full list of statements parsed from your source file:

```
evalString :: Env -> String -> IO String
evalString env expr = do
        x <- readStatement expr
        concat <$> mapM (runIOThrows . liftM show . evalStatement_ env) x 
                   ^^^^ runs on every statement in the list `x`
```

If the statement list `x :: [HStatement]` contains any `Program` or `Eval` statements, then this will cause a run-time error, since `evalStatement_` only handles the `Do` and `Print` constructors.

So, as @jpmarinier comments, if you expect to call `evalStatement_` on any valid statement, then you need to handle all cases that the compiler warns you about when you turn on `-Wall`.

The following definitions for the missing cases might work for you to get things running:

```
evalStatement_ env (Program pgm) = mapM_ (evalStatement_ env) pgm
evalStatement_ env (Eval val) = do
    result <- evalVal env val
    return ()
```

Note that the case for `Eval` is pretty useless.  Since `evalStatement_` can't return anything other than `()`, we end up calculating a result and then throwing it away.  It's going to be almost the same as just doing:

```
evalStatement_ _ (Eval _) = return ()  -- do nothing
```

Comment: That's perfect! I understand where the issue was coming from now but could I ask why it wasn't detected that what I was dealing with was `Do cond expr`? It seems that the error came about from the possibility that it could have been other statements rather than anything else. I'm assuming that it's probably just a quirk of Haskell but it was confusing given that I was trying to run a statement which was in the form of the `Do cond expr`

Comment: No, to be clear:  The compiler *warning* you received with `-Wall` was a result of the *possibility* that it could have been something other than `Do` or `Print`.  However, the runtime *error* you received when you actually ran the program would have been the result of the program *actually calling* `evalStatement_` with something other than `Do` or `Print`.  Check the result of parsing your source file.  Does the parsed list contain a `Program` or `Expr`?  If so, you are *actually* calling `evalStatement_` with a value it is unprepared to handle, so it is not a "quirk".